# MySQL server crash on TRUNCATE table with foreign key constraints

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I was running a web UI named pterodactyl panel : https://pterodactyl.io/ and after days of working fine, it crashed with the error message "Out of storage".
Obviously I did check and found that the disk was full, upon further investigation, a table named activity_logs in the panel database was using up almost 120 GB of space. I decided to clear the logs as I did not need them. I went ahead with a vacate command `TRUNCATE`. This was followed by an error:

```
Database changed
MariaDB [panel]> TRUNCATE TABLE activity_logs;
ERROR 1701 (42000): Cannot truncate a table referenced in a foreign key constraint (`panel`.`activity_log_subjects`, CONSTRAINT `activity_log_subjects_activity_log_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`activity_log_id`) REFERENCES `panel`.`activity_logs` (`id`))
```

I went ahead and disabled key constrains and ran `TRUNCATE` in the hopes that I would enable forgeign key checks once the table is empty.

Expected:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
TRUNCATE TABLE activity_logs;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
exit;
```

What I got instead was:

```
MariaDB [panel]> SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [panel]> TRUNCATE TABLE activity_logs;
ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server during query
MariaDB [panel]> TRUNCATE TABLE activity_logs;
ERROR 2006 (HY000): MySQL server has gone away
No connection. Trying to reconnect...
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (111)
ERROR: Can't connect to the server

unknown [panel]> exit
Bye
```

Not sure what to do in order to fix the issue.

Here is the log that i ran after:

````
root@Panel:/var/lib/mysql/panel# systemctl status mysql
● mariadb.service - MariaDB 10.4.27 database server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service.d
           └─migrated-from-my.cnf-settings.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2023-01-24 09:20:30 CET; 2s ago
     Docs: man:mysqld(8)
           https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/systemd/
  Process: 4680 ExecStartPost=/etc/mysql/debian-start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 4677 ExecStartPost=/bin/sh -c systemctl unset-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 6101 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld $MYSQLD_OPTS $_WSREP_NEW_CLUSTER $_WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 5952 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ ! -e /usr/bin/galera_recovery ] && VAR= ||   VAR=`cd /usr/bin/..; /usr/bin/galera_recovery`; [ $? -eq 0 ]   &  Process: 5943 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c systemctl unset-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 5931 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/install -m 755 -o mysql -g root -d /var/run/mysqld (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 6101 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Status: "MariaDB server is down"

Jan 24 09:20:29 Panel mysqld[6101]: 2023-01-24  9:20:29 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
Jan 24 09:20:30 Panel mysqld[6101]: 2023-01-24  9:20:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
Jan 24 09:20:30 Panel mysqld[6101]: 2023-01-24  9:20:30 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
Jan 24 09:20:30 Panel mysqld[6101]: 2023-01-24  9:20:30 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
Jan 24 09:20:30 Panel mysqld[6101]: 2023-01-24  9:20:30 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
Jan 24 09:20:30 Panel mysqld[6101]: 2023-01-24  9:20:30 0 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
Jan 24 09:20:30 Panel mysqld[6101]: 2023-01-24  9:20:30 0 [ERROR] Aborting
Jan 24 09:20:30 Panel systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jan 24 09:20:30 Panel systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jan 24 09:20:30 Panel systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB 10.4.27 database server.```
````

Comment: You could try renaming the redo logs (ib_logfile0 and ib_logfile1 in datadir) and then starting the server.

Comment: Thanks for the response, could you elaborate what do you mean by redo logs?

Comment: The two (possibly more) files named in my previous comment. Try `sudo mv ib_logfile0 __ib_logfile0` (and same for ib_logfile1) in the datadir (possibly /var/lib/mysql)